# Logstash Add field from grok filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Is it possible to match a message to a new field in logstash using grok and mutate?

Example log:

```
"<30>Dec 19 11:37:56 7f87c507df2a[20103]: [INFO] 2018-12-19 16:37:56 _internal (MainThread): 192.168.0.6 - - [19/Dec/2018 16:37:56] \"\u001b[37mGET / HTTP/1.1\u001b[0m\" 200 -\r"
```

I am trying to create a new key value where I match container_id to 7f87c507df2a.

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{SYSLOG5424PRI}%{NONNEGINT:ver} +(?:%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:ts}|-) +(?:%{HOSTNAME:service}|-) +(?:%{NOTSPACE:containerName}|-) +(?:%{NOTSPACE:proc}|-) +(?:%{WORD:msgid}|-) +(?:%{SYSLOG5424SD:sd}|-|) +%{GREEDYDATA:msg}" ]
  }
  mutate {
    add_field => { "container_id" => "%{containerName}"}
  }
}
```

The resulting logfile renders this, where the value of containerName isn't being referenced from grok, it is just a string literal:

```
"container_id": "%{containerName}"
```

I am trying to have the conf create:

```
"container_id": "7f87c507df2a"
```

Obviously the value of containerName isn't being linked from grok. Is what I want to do even possible?

Comment: I am not sure if I unterstand the question, but if so a simple `filter {
  mutate {
     copy => { "containerName" => "container_id" }
  }
}`
should do the job

Comment: anther thing you can try is adding `add_field => { "container_id" => "%{containerName}"}` directly into the `grok` part - but if "containerName" is not matched in the grok pattern the key/value pair is not added to the result.

Comment: @Quali neither have worked, is there an easier way to test that my grok matching is working properly? There seems to be no errors in the logs of logstash however. I updated the post with an example log file and what I am trying to do

Comment: You can use https://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match

Comment: Seems like your pattern is not matching the exmple logline.

Comment: Your SYSLOG5424PRI matches "30", but %{NONNEGINT:ver} isn't going to match "Dec".  Use the grok debugger to build your pattern up slowly from left to right: https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Or if you only want to grab `7f87c507df2a` and the container is always present at the same place in the logs, you can just use `%{NOTSPACE:containerName}\[`, using the `[` to find the containerName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the comments, my grok pattern was incorrect. For anyone that may wander towards this post that needs help with grok go [here](https://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/construction) to make building your pattern less time consuming.

Here was the working snapshot:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "\A%{SYSLOG5424PRI}%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP}%{SPACE}%{BASE16NUM:docker_id}%{SYSLOG5424SD}%{GREEDYDATA:python_log_message}" ]
    add_field => { "container_id" => "%{docker_id}" }    
  }  
}
```